# Can't start my meteor app on a centos7 DO server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cordova, meteor

I just git cloned from Telescope's git repository and run meteor, but it can't start the app successfully. How to deal with this ?  I've googled but I can't get a easy to follow solution.

> => Started proxy.
>   => Started MongoDB.                            nova:rss: updating npm dependencies -- rss...                                   Unexpected
>   mongo exit code null. Restarting.
>                                                  /root/.meteor/packages/coffeescript/.1.0.17.1qmihgc++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileCoffeescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:116
>         throw error;
>               ^ Error: spawn ENOMEM
>       at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
>       at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:958:11)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:746:9)
>       at spawnMongod (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:45:24)
>       at launchOneMongoAndWaitForReadyForInitiate (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:468:12)
>       at launchMongo (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:682:7)
>       at MongoRunner._startOrRestart (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:789:19)
>       at [object Object]. (/tools/runners/run-mongo.js:857:14)
>       at runWithEnvironment (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:112:21)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js catch ENOMEM error thrown after spawn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193654/node-js-catch-enomem-error-thrown-after-spawn)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the case, I have 0 swap space.  But it says that using swap with SSDs can cause issues with hardware. Do you have any other suggestion for my situation?