# Express or Node JS memory causes spawn ENOMEM

Tags: node.js, express

It appears my express server is juicing all the memory on my sever.  I'm only taking a guess at this.  I have a process which is running at:

```
node server.js
```

This loads a server, receives some data from another server and takes a screen shot.  Everything works and it works for a day or so.  Then out of nowhere, with no code changes it randomly starts crashing with this error:

```
internal/child_process.js:366
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn ENOMEM
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:366:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:551:9)
```

I originally had 2 gigs of memory on my server.  The process would work and much faster it would give me this error.  I bumped up the memory to 3 gigs and it lasted a lot longer, over a day and then it started happening again.  Running a check of memory in my server.js file I get this:

```
{ rss: 30277632,
  heapTotal: 20168704,
  heapUsed: 12109848,
  external: 497984 }
```

From my command line I run:  `free -m`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3072       2223        848          3          0       1107
-/+ buffers/cache:       1115       1956
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Someone in another post suggested adding swap memory.  Unfortunately on my server provider this doesn't seem possible.

My guess is that it sucks memory until it runs out then I start getting the error.  Is there anyway I can clean out the memory cache from express to clean up some space?  I'm not too familiar with this. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32444643/1427161

Comment: It's possible that you have a memory leak as well, which a swap file will not help with.

Comment: @doublesharp that's the question I was talking about when I said I couldn't add swap memory on mine for some reason.  Do you have any suggestion for how to diagnose a memory leak?

Comment: Actually I can do swap memory, let me try that @doublesharp

Comment: Ugh just confirmed I can't add swap space from hosting provider.  Any work arounds? @doublesharp

Comment: You will need to use heap snapshots to study what is taking an increasing amount of memory over time.  One classic work-around is to just restart your server every so often (often at something like 4am) so that any memory that has leaked somehow is reclaimed and you start with a fresh server instance every day

Comment: Great, thank you! @jfriend00

Comment: It could also be that you are running out of some resource (other than actual memory) that your hosting provider puts limits on in the environment you run in.

Comment: How often is your code spawning a new process?  Are you possibly leaking those processes - not shutting them down so that they accumulate over time, each taking some memory.

Comment: Every couple of minutes.  So I run node server.js for example to get started.  Server files up then that server is getting hit sometimes every few seconds.  @jfriend00

Comment: What exactly do you mean by shutting down the process? @jfriend00

Comment: I'm suggesting (as a work-around) a regular restart of your server to reset its memory usage back to what it is at start.  Are you really spawning a new process every few seconds?  Pls show us your code that uses `spawn()`.  Have you checked the process manager to see how many spawned processes are running?

Comment: I'm running a package which uses phantoms and some other stuff.  I'll have to check how many are running in that.  Thank you for all your help your work around I think will work!  @jfriend00

Comment: FYI, I have a small local server (home automation) that is started with `forever` which will automatically restart the server any time it stops.  So, I just programmed my server to do an orderly `process.exit()` at 4am every night and after it stops, `forever` just starts it up again automatically.  Been working like a charm for 4 years.