# Angular ng serve produces Error: NGCC failed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

After running `ng serve` I've got an exception in terminal window:

Compiling @angular/core : module as esm5

```
Error: Error on worker #1: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

and message below:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.
```

See `/tmp/ng-EAdxWj/angular-errors.log` for further details.

#### *angular-errors.log*

```
[error] Error: NGCC failed.
    at NgccProcessor.process (/IdeaProjects/app/frontend/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:76:19)
    at /IdeaProjects/app/frontend/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:579:31
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/IdeaProjects/app/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (/IdeaProjects/app/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Object.webpack [as webpackFactory] (/IdeaProjects/app/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:55:30)
    at createWebpack (/IdeaProjects/app/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack/src/webpack-dev-server/index.js:20:36)
    at Object.runWebpackDevServer (/IdeaProjects/app/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack/src/webpack-dev-server/index.js:46:12)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (/IdeaProjects/app/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server/index.js:191:32)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (/IdeaProjects/app/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js:49:27)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/IdeaProjects/app/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at /IdeaProjects/app/frontend/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToPromise.js:7:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your code?

Comment: No. Any errors no more. First I has version coflict NPM and NodeJs.

Comment: does anyone have figure it out how to get rid off ? I am having same issue.

Comment: One of your dependencies probably causing it, did upgrade package.json?

Comment: For me, the issue was with @angular/flex-layout when I removed that dependency then my app built. I'll troubleshoot it more, but that's the dependency that was causing issues.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I just had the same issue and fixed it by adding following to the *tsconfig.app.json* file:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
},
```

Comment: Why does this work? The app works perfectly in a workmate's computer, but not in mine. This solved it, but it's not really the solution, as this fix is not ideal.

Comment: This error started for me after installing the flex-layout module, and remained even after I removed the faulty module.  This workaround fixed the problem but, like you, I would like to understand what happened.

Comment: @Felix, this means you disable the Ivy compiler and so use the old compiler (AOT). Are your sure, this is the right solution ?

Comment: I'm using Angular 11, there is only `tsconfig.json`, not `tsconfig.app.json`. And only `compilerOptions`, not `angularCompilerOptions`. Still added and got `enableIvy is not a valid option.`

Comment: How disabling `ivy` is a solution?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanHashem It is not, and actually in 14 there is no such option anymore.

Answer (score 6):

I had the error:

```
Unknown arguments: use-program-dependencies, useProgramDependencies
An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.
See "C:\...\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I just updated [Angular CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)), material and core, and other modules needed to my project, then updated the npm and the TypeScript package, and that's all.

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
npm update @angular/material @angular/cdk
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

Answer (score 6):

In my particular case, the @angular-devkit/build-angular was updated to "^0.1002.0" in my *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* file after running the npm audit fix. (This version seems to belong to Angular 10, instead of the local projects' angular version (v9.1.3).)

After reverting this change, everything started working again:

"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.12"

Comment: ng update to v9 upgraded from v8 successfully, except for this package, which was `~0.1100.2` instead of 9.

Set manually the version solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Linux setup locally and on a remote server. Locally it works, remotely I had "NGCC failed". Not very informative.

So I started to reinstall everything: nodejs, npm, ng. I tried to purge and invalidate caches. Nothing helped.

Then at some point I got:

> ENOMEM error thrown after spawn

Which brought me to [Node.js catch ENOMEM error thrown after spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193654/node-js-catch-enomem-error-thrown-after-spawn)

Indeed my hosting is 1 GB RAM and no swap. So I added it and magically ngcc started to work.

Now I wonder whether swap fixed it or my efforts to reinstall everything on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I got this on Angular 11

Any version of TypeScript above 4.1 causes failure

4.8+ will fail with NGCC error

Set TypeScript version in `package.json` as follows:

```
"typescript": "~4.1.6"
```