# npm ERR! ENOMEM: not enough memory, read

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install, angular11

While running any angular commands i am getting this error > npm ERR! ENOMEM: not enough memory, read

any fix for this??

[image: refer image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js catch ENOMEM error thrown after spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193654/node-js-catch-enomem-error-thrown-after-spawn)

Comment: thanks praveen..it is not related to my question ,when i am trying to build my application i am getting this error ..it is not related to running node files

Answer (score 2):

`export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192`

Answer (score -1):

You will need to adjust the max memory ceiling in your node builds to avoid this issue. Look to the following support article describes how to accomplish this :

https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009208393-How-can-I-increase-the-max-memory-for-Node-